# Socket.io - How to get client URL request on server side?

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

In my app.js (server) I need to know from where (URL) the request came.

Currently, I'm passing the URL as parameter from the client:

```
socket.emit('request', window.location.href);
```

and processing it server side

```
socket.on('request', function(url){
    console.log(url);
    ...
});
```

But that's clearly risky and unsecure (clients can send anything to the server).

So I'm guessing.. is it possible to get the URL parameter only on server side? Maybe from the socket object?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29358328/determine-url-of-client-request-from-server-side-socket-io

Answer (score 3):

For the entire URL you could use socket.handshake.headers.referer

```
io.on('connect', (socket) => {
     console.log(socket.handshake.headers.referer);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

To obtain the connection URL

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {

    console.log("url: " + socket.handshake.url);

});
```

This will return something like: `url: /socket.io/1/?t=1407807394827`

Comment: Will it return something like www.example.com/socket.io/1/?t=1407807394827 for cross domain?

Answer (score 0):

socket.request.headers.origin
This will return domain connection